# Getting MarkLogic error - Host is not resolvable error while running mlcp command

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to use the import with mlcp and my MarkLogic server is running fine.
However, I see this Host not resolvable error after running the mlcp import command.
My hostname is correct when I checked in the MarkLogic instance.

Is it referring to any other MarkLogic instance running in my system ?
How can I confirm if there is only 1 marklogic server running in my machine?

This is the error

```
deploy-tde:latest
RUNNING




Config file found.Options file found. Adding it to MLCP argumentsnRead the config fileconfigfile read.ngetopt executedgetopt check executedmandatory argument providedMLCP Auth Credentials:nnUser Provided MLCP Options used for this run:

-options_file /opt/mlcp-10.0.9-bin/mlcp-10.0.9/bin/mlcp_config.txtnmlcp import command started22/10/13 08:37:33 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host owc-db01.owc.com is not resolvable
```

Comment: (1) please share the content of the options file (except for user and password if in there)  (2) are you deploying against a load balancer

Comment: Content of option file : IMPORT
-input_file_path
/opt/mlcp-10.0.9-bin/mlcp-10.0.9/bin/data/MyFirstTDE.xml
-input_file_type 
documents
-document_type 
xml
-host
localhost
-port
8000
-database
GTM2_TEST1
-output_uri_prefix
/MyFirstTDE.xml
-output_collections
Docker_DeployTDE

Comment: Ans 2) Not deploying against any load balancer. I am trying to deploy by creating a docker image and running the container, installed the docker locally in my windows system. The problem is the same option file works fine when I run from the windows terminal but gives me unresolved host issue when trying from docker.

Comment: OK. You mention localhost in the MLCP config file.  But then the error is referencing a different hostname (likely the hostname configured in Marklogic itself).  Issue-1 I see is that ML is telling MLCP to use a hostname that is not  known to your windows machine (1) make sure that owc-db01.owc.com resolves to the IP address of the docker container or possibly (2) use the MLCP import option "-restrict_hosts" to keep using your connection host.   I did not work this into a response because it is just a guess, you should really explain more (config file and docker use) in the main post to help